# Is there a registry value to force a connection to close?

Tags: ethernet, tcpip

I have an ethernet connection that I want to close if it's not sending or receiving any data.  Is there a registry value I can set or any configurations I can change?

For windows 10, thanks

Edit: Maybe something like TcpTimedWaitDelay set to 1 would work?  I want the connection closed so that it has to make a new connection everytime it wants to talk.

Or:

TcpInitialRTT: Defines what the initial time-out settings are for new connections. This number in seconds is doubled each time it retransmits before timing a connection out. Defaults to 3.

TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions: Defines the number of retransmissions while establishing the connection before timing a connection out. Defaults to 2.

Comment: What does `close if it's not sending or receiving any data` mean? Over what time period? Do you want to shut it down? Then it's not useable anymore. What do you want to *achieve*?

Comment: I have some software code that is supposed to send a message within a short window of time after it connects to the TCP server.  I have found that this software keeps failing because the connection is never closed.   The software is supposed to make a connection, then immediately send a message.  What's actually happening is it sees the connection is already open and sends the message.  The message is discarded because it is way past that small window of time.  I want it to close at the end, so it is forced to make a new connection every time.

Comment: It's probably easier to fix the software so that it closes the connection upon sending the message...

Comment: I wish I could. It’s not my software and it works on all the other machines except this one. There must be some setting that’s different. I can even get it to work once if I make changes to the Ethernet settings, it must reset the connection or something because after that the software works correctly once. And then returns to failing every time after that.